# Script working manually but not via crontab

Tags: linux, bash, shell, cron

I am new to Shell scripts and working on a script which will delete older items from my Digital ocean bucket (SPACES)

Script is working when run manually but giving error when i use crontab
and i have seen other similar questions but were not helpful

**Script:**

```
#!/bin/bash

/usr/local/bin/s3cmd -c ~/Bucket_Name ls s3://$1 | while read -r line;
  do
    createDate=`echo $line|awk {'print $1" "$2'}`
    createDate=`date -d"$createDate" +%s`
    olderThan=`date -d"-$2" +%s`
    #echo $line
    #echo $createDate
    #echo $olderThan
    #echo $1
    #echo $2
    if [[ $createDate -lt $olderThan ]]
      then
        fileName=`echo $line|awk {'print $4'}`
        #echo $fileName
        if [[ $fileName != "" ]]
          then
            #printf 'FILE' $fileName
            if [[ $fileName == *"sql" ]]
              then
                /usr/local/bin/s3cmd -c ~/Bucket_Name rm "$fileName"
            fi
        fi
    fi
  done;
```

**Manual Command (Working):**

```
./sqlclear.sh "Bucket_Name" "300 minutes"
```

**Crontab Command :**

```
* * * * * sh /sqldump/sqlclear.sh "Bucket_Name" "300 minutes" >> /var/log/sql-clear.log 2>&1
```

**Error Cron Log (sql-clear.log  from above):**

```
/sqldump/sqlclear.sh: 13: /sqldump/sqlclear.sh: [[: not found
```

Comment: use `bash` instead of `sh` in the cron. i.e `sh /sqldump/sqlclear.sh` to `bash /sqldump/sqlclear.sh`

Comment: You have used `sh` in your cron and you have a shebang for `bash`.

Comment: `~/Bucket_Name` - this might be your problem. Crontab runs scripts as SU not as your user. Try providing full path to all files inside the script.

Comment: @AlexM Cron runs as whoever you run it as...

Comment: @123 AFAIK, that's only if you create it for specific user via `crontab -u <username> -e`

Comment: @ AlecM  i am giving full path

Comment: @123  yes that was the problem

Comment: @AlexM Yes which is typically what people do unless there is a specific reason to be running as root.

Answer (score 0):

I missed Bash while running in crontab 
so 
crontab should be

```
* * * * * bash /sqldump/sqlclear.sh
```

Comment: You can completely skip `bash`, it's not necessary. `/sqldump/sqlclear.sh` is enough.